# Cannot Add Control Variable

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, atl, image

I have an application that I want to add a picture control and show some bitmap images inside it. However, I can't add a control variable to the picture control.

In the beginning, I couldn't even add a variable. Because there was no `enum {IDD = ID_OF_MY_DIALOG;}` line in my header file. I fixed it. However, now, I can't add a control variable. When I right click on a picture control, and click on Add Variable line, I can't choose the Control Variable checkbox.

How can I add a control variable to my project, how can I show a bitmap dynamically, or what's my error here?

I tested some MFC applications and saw the control variable part. So, there must be something missing in my project - I guess.

Here are my screenshots:

[Add Variable Screen in my ATL project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/prrq3xle2mvuelr/atlBased.PNG)

[Add Variable Screen in a random MFC project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbkyabh4kmcyo6x/mfcBased.PNG)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you added `STATIC` control into dialog template. Right there in template editor, in control properties you can assign an identifier, e.g. `IDC_PICTURE`. From there - the control already will be created on runtime for you. In code, you will add `CWindow` variable, and in your `OnInitDialog` handler (I assume you already have it - AFAIR it is created by default and exists is various samples) you will add member variable initialization, so it will be available to your code for further things like message processing.

```
class CMainDialog :
    public CDialogImpl<CMainDialog>
{
// ...
private:
    CWindow m_PictureStatic;
    HBITMAP m_hPictureBitmap;

// Window Message Handlers
    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT nMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        m_PictureStatic = GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE);
        m_hPictureBitmap = LoadBitmap(_AtlBaseModule.GetResourceInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PICTURE));
        ATLASSERT(m_hPictureBitmap);
        m_PictureStatic.SendMessage(STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) m_hPictureBitmap);
        // ...
    }
    LRESULT OnDestroy(UINT nMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        ATLVERIFY(DeleteObject(m_hPictureBitmap));
        return 0;
    }
```

The picture itself is (in this code snippet, there might be other options) a bitmap resource with identifier `IDB_PICTURE`. The code loads bitmap from resource and passes it to the control.

[image]

[Source Code](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/AtlDialogSample) + [Source Code before adding Picture Static](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/AtlDialogSample?rev=71).

Comment: Thank you for your response, again. I have some problems now. Can you check these out? I couldn't find a solution and it's still not working. I uploaded some screenshots to show you stuff, and added the error message (after I click OK/Cancel button) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z26g80dujrowa4i/loadBitmapP.PNG). The bitmap is not here, nor the picture control. [Screenshot is here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z26g80dujrowa4i/loadBitmapP.PNG). Thank you very much, again.

Comment: I added the bitmap from resources like this: `HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadBitmap(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));` However, it still fails. And don't laugh at me, but I don't have any handle instance in my OnInitDialog(). Thank you very much.

Comment: I updated that old project and it loads bitmap now, see updated answer and source code links above.

Comment: You're great. There's no documentation on the internet whatsoever and you're my savior all the time. I don't know what would I do if you weren't here answering my questions. Even the silly ones. Thank you very much. I owe you - as always. I hope all the happiness and good things find their way to you and make you the happiest person on earth ever. I will post my poems about you in the future. Knowing that much, yet helping newbies... You are my hero. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think ATL is poorly documented. Thanks for the response !

Comment: In vs2013, `CWnd m_PictureStatic`;